# Exception caught by widgets library null check to xfile to file

Tags: flutter

When I build after changing Xfile to file, it says null check operator user on a null value, but I don't know what the problem is

The code is too long, so I'll just write the gist

please help me......

```
XFile? _imageFile; 
File file = File(_imageFile!.path);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Are you picking any file in XFile or just declaring it?
   Then of course you're going to get null value

Otherwise,
Add a check when you've picked a file from user

```
XFile? imageFile;
imageFile = //Your File Picking logic
if(imageFile != null) {
  File _file = File(imageFile!.path);
}
```

Else you can also try reading the bytes if in any case your file path is inaccessible and create a new file object

```
imageFile!.readAsBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

### What does a null check operator?

This operator (`!`) throws an exception when a nullable variable wasn't initialized (so, it's null).

[image: screenshot]

### How do I fix the error?

Since in your code the `XFile? _imageFile` variable is **nullable** (indicated by the `?`), probably it turns out to be actually `null` when being assigned to a `File` object.

A quick solution the null check problem could be this:

```
late File file;
XFile? _imageFile; 
if (_imageFile != null) {
   file = File(_imageFile!.path);
}
```

But in your exact code, what you should really do is initialize `_imageFile`, as right now you are just declaring it.

```
XFile? _imageFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); //Example with image_picker package
```

Comment: ```
Widget imageProfile() {
    XFile? _imageFile; 
    File file;
    if (_imageFile != null) {
     file = File(_imageFile!.path);
    }

    return Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
              radius: 80,
              backgroundImage: _imageFile == null
                  ? AssetImage('assets/test.jpg') as ImageProvider
                  : FileImage(file)), //error
```
and it has a The non-nullable local variable 'file' must be assigned before it can be used.
i,m assigned file value...

Comment: The problem is that the `File` is declared inside the `if` statement. I updated the code so you can better understand. Keep in mind that if the `_imageFile` variable continues to be null, this will always cause an error. It's up to you to initialize it, picking a file. As right now, you are just declaring it. I added an example.